# genericdaohibernate add getbyfield other than id

Tags: java, hibernate, appfuse

I am using `org.appfuse.dao.hibernate`package and I have used all the method in the `GenericDaoHibernate<T,PK>` class.

I found these methods

```
public List<T> getAll();
public List<T> getAllDistinct();
public List<T> search(String searchTerm);
public T get(PK id);
public boolean exists(PK id);
public T save(T object);
public void remove(T object);
public void remove(PK id);
public List<T> findByNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> queryParams);
public void reindex();
public void reindexAll(boolean async);
```

I have some model classes, services and methods.

Now I want to get list of object using some other fieled in the model class other than id(I have some common fields in many model classes).
I need to write similar methods in all the services and daos. So i was thinking is it possible to create a common method in generic dao.

The following I tried, but it didn't work.

```
public T getbyClientKey(Long clientkey) {
        Session sess = getSession();
        IdentifierLoadAccess byId = sess.byId(persistentClass);
        List<T> entity = (List<T>) byId.load(clientkey);

        if (entity == null) {
            log.warn("Uh oh, '" + this.persistentClass + "' object with client '" + clientkey + "' not found...");
            throw new ObjectRetrievalFailureException(this.persistentClass, clientkey);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

I knew this will be error. and it showed **TypeCastingException**, because return type of `byId.load(id)` is **object** only, not **List**.

So how can I create a method like that?
If so, I think I can create method for **remove()** also(But that's not necessary for me now, may be in future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Javadoc for `IdentifierLoadAccess`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/IdentifierLoadAccess.html) is pretty clear in how the `load` method should behave:

> Return the persistent instance with the given identifier, or null if there is no such persistent instance.

This means it should return just one object, not a `List` of objects. Try casting it to `T` instead.

<del>If you want to query your entity (that is, retrieve items by any other means than primary key), you most likely want to implement the [`search(String)`](http://static.appfuse.org/appfuse-data/appfuse-hibernate/apidocs/org/appfuse/dao/hibernate/GenericDaoHibernate.html#search%28java.lang.String%29) method.</del>

If you want to query your entity (that is, retrieve items by any other means than primary key), take a look at the `UserDaoHibernate` that is shipped with AppFuse. It contains a method `loadUserByUsername()` which is implemented like this:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    List users = getSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("username", username)).list();
    if (users == null || users.isEmpty()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user '" + username + "' not found...");
    } else {
        return (UserDetails) users.get(0);
    }
}
```

Obviously, if you want to return **all** items, it should be modified a bit (this one is made up):

```
public List<UserDetails> loadLockedUsers() {
    List<UserDetails> users = (List<UserDetails>) getSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("account_locked", true)).list();
    return users;
}
```

Comment: That I know. I want to get as `List<Object>` that too without id. I mean the `clientkey` value i am passing is not Id of the Object. Is there anyway for that?

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to use that search method?
because first I tried that search method. instead of query, i passed the clientkey value as String ( `mymanagaerclass.search(Long.toString(clientKey), mymanagagerclass.class)` )